# How small could we make a seed for a non-nanotech von Neumann machine?

Tags: science-based, technology

Nanotech von Neumann machines can obviously be made quite small--bacteria are existence proofs!

But what if we don't want to rely on biology, or any any sort of magic nanotech?

At the other end of the scale, human civilization is a kind of von Neumann machine. It's a bit of a cheat, because it relies on a core of nanotech von Neumann machines (humans) to function, but one could imagine developing the technology to build humanoid robots, which could then operate the machine to make humanoid robots, and actual humans are then out of the equation.

That, however, seems like a very inefficient way to go about things; surely there are simpler ways to automate the production of new machines than by building exact replicas of humans to operate manufacturing facilities in the same ways humans would!

Now, it seems plausible that a von Neumann machine in operation may need to spread out over a civilization-sized area to acquire resources and set up all of its functional subcomponents, just like plant seeds (another example of proper nanotech von Neumann machines) need to grow into plants before they can actually duplicate themselves. But, plants *can* package their reproductive capacity into relatively tiny seeds.

So: how small could we plausibly make a non-nanotech von Neumann machine seed? I don't care much about how big the machine "grows" while unpacked and in operation, but how small can we make the package that does the unpacking and growing, that contains everything it needs to make the parts to make the parts to make the parts to make copies of itself?

Comment: Since this question heavily hinges on what is and isn't considered nanotech, you should define exactly what you mean by the term.

Comment: Currently we cannot make production facilities that run wholly without (human) supervision, period.  But that aside, what environment are you proposing for your machines to run in?  An (empty) Earth, with biologically friendly atmosphere?  Mars?  The asteroid belt?  A different solar system?  All of the above?  What a solution would look like depends on the conditions the technology has to endure.

Comment: @Jedediah Whichever environment allows for making the smallest seed.

Comment: @sphennings "the branch of technology that deals with dimensions and tolerances of less than 100 nanometers, especially the manipulation of individual atoms and molecules."

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley Wouldn't a bacteria not count then since they don't have any dimensional tolerances and instead work stochastically, via chemical processes without manipulating individual atoms or molecules.

Comment: @sphennings Bacteria most certainly *do* manipulate individual atoms and molecules, and have functional mechanical components (ATPases, flagellate rotors, motor proteins, ribosomes) that operate on the nanometer scale. Doing so deterministically vs. stochastically is not part of the quoted definition.

Comment: Also, is it just me or is this question either trivially answered or 100% opinion-based? Simplifying things a bit, DNA is the smallest known von Neumann machine, right? Do we have any evidence at all of something smaller than DNA that's self-replicating? If not, then DNA is as small as it gets, right?

Comment: @JBH DNA, by itself, isn't a machine. It does nothing without a large complex of nanomachinery (transcriptases and ribosomes) around it. Also... nanomachine.

Comment: @JBH DNA is not self replicating, RNA is self replicating, DNA is a way to store RNA data long term but it cannot replicate on its own.

Comment: @John I'm grateful you got my point, though! I'm not a biologist, but the basic question remains. Call it RNA (heck, from the layman's perspective, call it DNA...) it's that basic engine that replicates life. Is that not by definition the smallest von Neumann machine?

Comment: @JBH Yes, you could reasonably call self-catalyzing RNAs the smallest possible von Neumann machines--but *not* the smallest non-nanotech von Neumann machines, as they directly manipulate materials on the atomic scale.

Answer (score 5):

While you have the `science-based` tag on the question, the answer is "We don't know."

We cannot currently build generalised self-replicating machines in the real world, never mind ones that can also build almost anything else. Designing a "smallest possible" one will inevitably require being able to build ones without that constraint, and then figuring out how to make smaller ones. If the history of modern technology is any guide, there will be ways of making smaller ones that are not obvious without experience of making larger ones.